# Convert CSV file To Mysql (.sql) database file?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am using :
WampServer 2.2,
Apache Version :2.2.21,
PHP Version : 5.3.8,
MySQL Version :5.5.16,
PhpMyadmin Version: 3.4.5...

I have face Problem Of Importing CSV file-(size 13MB*), Error File is Too large...
phpMyadmin allow only 2MB file size ...

So Separate files with 1.83MB file size...then also it does not work ???

And also tell me , How to automatic create table through CSV file ...?

Comment: what error do you get when you try with 1.83 mb files?

Answer (score 10):

Why dont you try to import file using MySQL Console?
I think, you will not face any problem this way. You will not need to split the file into chunks. Just take care of syntax.

```
load data infile 'c:/filename.csv' into table tablename fields terminated by ',';
```

For details about syntax, refer [Load Data Infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) on official documentation.
For example, refer [this](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2345/import_csv_file_directly_into_mysql/) and [this](http://jameshd.wordpress.com/2010/04/08/mysql-load-data-infile-examples/).

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: If my suggestion has helped you, can you please upvote or accept answer?

Answer (score 4):

`LOAD DATA INFILE 'your.csv' 
INTO TABLE android_dev 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;`

include the csv file in your database folder,i.e., `<root>\mysql\data\DATABASE_NAME`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you look at [Data Transformer](https://geosystemsdev.com/products/data-transformer/) (disclaimer - I'm its developer). It can convert CSV/JSON/XML to SQL. The generated SQL contains "insert" statements for each line and a "create table" statement.

The app works offline and your data never leaves your computer.

You can get it from the [Mac App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/data-transformer/id1490843070) or the [Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/p/data-transformer/9p2xp6nt2pv2).

Answer (score 1):

> How to automatic create table through CSV file ...?

I wrote a csv2mysql command. It scans the entier CSV file to determine appropriate column types and outputs a CREATE TABLE statement and (optionally) INSERT INTO statements for the data.

It's at
https://github.com/artfulrobot/csv2mysql
(you can just download the `bin/csv2mysql` executable (Linux) or you can run the main csv2mysql.php file if you download the source and run `composer install`)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using [sqlizer.io](http://sqlizer.io). Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of sqlizer.io]

Just select "Comma Separated Values" for the file type and upload your file. It will analyse the data and generate an SQL script containing an appropriate CREATE TABLE statement, and a lot of INSERT statements.

(Disclaimer: I help run SQLizer)

Comment: By not disclosing your affiliation, this is considered SPAM. 
https://d4nt.com/how-sqlizer-io-became-the-internets-1-database-import-tool/

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres ok, I've added a disclaimer. It's a freemium tool that I run part time and I was only trying to be helpful.

Comment: Understandable. I've done a quick search and most of the posts including sqlizer.io were from you and / or other team members and none disclose the affiliation.

Answer (score 0):

One of the best option which i frequently use is rebasedata, they allow around 200 MB (CSV to MySQL, which I tested) in their free plan.

Checkout yourself here https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-csv-to-mysql-online

Answer (score 0):

Use https://csvtosql.com online CSV to SQL converter tool. Paste your CSV lines and Convert them to SQL queries. Then you can save them in a SQL file or directly run them on SQL console on phpmyadmin

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcPfn.png)

Comment: This answer might be a security risk dependending on the data to be converted!

Answer (score -1):

Go to ..\xampp\php\php.ini

and change following...

```
    php_value upload_max_filesize xxxxM //file size
    php_value post_max_size xxxxM
    php_value max_execution_time xxxx
    php_value max_input_time xxxx
```

put xxxx your desire value 1M = 1mb

You most restart your server after changing...